# Proving a very simple uniqueness.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Apologizes for the sloppy proof, but this I've just started doing these in uni. I feel this is inaccurate, so can some of you help me with why it might not be good? Much appreciated.

**Prove there is a unique real number x such that the floor of x = the ceiling of x = 8.**

So I know one way of showing uniqueness is to

1. Find at least one answer that satisfies what I'm looking for.
2. Assume there is another distinct solution.
3. Find a contradiction.

So for this problem I wrote:

When x=8, the floor of x = the ceiling of x = 8.

Assume there is a second solution, x ≠ 8. 
However, (floor of x = the ceiling of x) iff x is an integer.
This means that (floor of 8 = the ceiling of 8  = 8) iff x = 7.
This contradicts the second solution, x ≠ 8. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you quote is a good one.  Your proof has three problems.  First, the statement after However seems like assuming what you are expected to prove.  If you have that theorem, you can cite it, but I suspect you are expected to answer the question without it.  Second, you only deal with integral $x$.  Third you seem to only think of the possibility that $x \lt 8$.

I would verify that $8$ satisfies the requirement, as you have done.  Now assume some $x \neq 8$ also satisfies it.  By trichotomy we have either $x \lt 8$ or $x \gt 8$.  In the first case $\lfloor x \rfloor \le 7$ and in the second ...

Answer (score 0):

When the floor and the ceiling of a number are the same the number is an integer.

In your question this integer must be $8$ therefore it is unique.